# Eclipse RCP - Product dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, product

I am finding it difficult to see the difference between the plugins listed in the Debug Configuration's `Plug-ins` tab of my product launch config and the ones in my dependencies tab in the product file.

My product is based on features and it is for an RCP application.

If a launch config has been created automatically when I click on the `Launch an Eclipse application in Debug mode` via the Overview tab of the product file, then in the Debug Configurations `Plug-ins` tab I have 174 plugins selected. My RCP application runs without any warnings or errors in my Console.

[image]

Now if I deselect all the plugins in the product launch config and then click `Add Required Plugins`, only 70 are selected. When I now run it, I get many warnings on missing imported pacakge, bundle not resolved and missing required bundle in my development Console.

The reason I am trying to understand this, is that I am not sure why the `Add Required Plugins` is not adding the additional 104 plugins and I do not want a problem when I export this as a product.

Comment: Did you click a second time on the *Add Required Plugins* button?

Comment: Yes I had multiple times

Answer (score 2):

The launch configuration itself is not used to decide which plugins to include in during the product export. As you say, the plugins included in the features that you have listed in the product dependency tab will comprise the built product.

When you deselect and click 'Add all required plugins' do you have the 'include optional dependecies' checkbox selected?

Comment: Yes I have the include optional dependencies checkbox selected.